# Log-likelihood: NA Flexmix package in R

Tags: r, regression

I am using Flexmix function from flexmix package for regression analysis in R. For some datasets I get following error:

Error in FLXfit(model = model, concomitant = concomitant, control = control,  : 1 Log-likelihood: NA

I don't know, are there any solution of this error?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is coming from a failure to converge. Looking at the code on github (https://github.com/cran/flexmix/blob/348da484b3a68943a5d9233814446b77f206e687/R/flexmix.R), it looks like there's a bug because of a numerical error (line 195). The best would be to untar the package source and debug it manually by looking at what is causing the error (where in the code is the NA being produced).

Best,

Diego